# Can we publish to multiple topics at the same time using mosquitto_pub client?

Tags: mqtt, iot, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

When I try to publish to different topics using same client id it disconnects the previous connection.

It says the mosquitto_pub publishes a single message at a time so was wondering if this is a limitation.

Answer (score 1):

MQTT Client Ids **MUST** be unique across all clients connected to the broker. The spec says the broker must disconnect any existing client when a new client with the same client id tries to connect.

The `mosquitto_pub` command will only publish a single message to a single topic (unless reading from a file or stdin, in which case it publishes a message per line, but again to a single topic).

If you want a single client to publish to multiple topics then you should look at one of the many MQTT client libraries and built a client that meets your needs.